# Using Vite in Laravel to load js libraries

Tags: laravel, vite

I must be making some rookie mistake somewhere but I can't figure out what it is.

I am trying to load js libraries and images into my blade view but I only get the error (in production, development works fine)

**Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/libraries/modernizr/modernizr-webp.js.**

my `vite.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
       }),
    ],
});
```

`resources.app.js`

```js
import.meta.glob([
    '../libraries/**'
]);
```

And I have

```php
<script src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/libraries/modernizr/modernizr-webp.js') }}"></script>

@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

in the `<head>` of my blade template.

I've tried using `Vite::asset()` as well as `@vite()` both giving the same result.
I have also tried changing the glob from `../resources/**` to `../resources/modernizr/*` but at this point I assume the problem is somewhere else.

I don't yet understand all this bundling stuff nor the different ways of importing things in JavaScript.

Note: I **have** run `npm ci` and `npm run build` on the server to install deps and build assets.

I'd appreciate some help. This is my first Laravel project and whilst developing it was a joy, I can't say the same about deploying.

Comment: did you build your assets? ´npm run build´

Comment: I did. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here, I've found a way to achieve what I wanted. Not sure if this is **the** way to do it, but it does the trick.

Instead of loading the libraries in `resources.app.js` I have added them to the `input` array in `vite.config.js`. They can now be loaded into blade views using the `@vite()` directive.

Comment: That does shows the file on html but it renders as a link tag and the script functions does not work. Is there any way to render the `.js` file as script tag and `.css` file as `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag